# Обнуление всех TextBox во всех программе

Tags: c#

Приветствую, гуру.

Собственно, вот сабж. Нужно обнулить все текстбоксы, их порядка 95 штук. Гуглил, пробовал в цикл запихнуть, не получалось. Есть ли какой-то способ обнулить всё и разом? На форме множество вкладок, подвкладок, и всё это надо очистить.

Comment: Это у вас на одной форме 95 текстбоксов?

Comment: Да, на одной форме, просто рассованые по вкладкам

Comment: Нормальные люди так не делают и поэтому таких проблем у них не возникает. Разделяйте свою уберформу на отдельные формы (каждая вкладка - отдельная форма), наследуйте их от интерфейса с методом Reset и регистрируйте каждую форму как содержимое соответствующей вкладки в рантайме.

Comment: Не прокатит, ибо проект рассчитан на просчет множества изменяющихся значений. Они всегда меняются, и поэтому такая вундервафля получилась

Comment: Для начала: WPF или WinForms? Если WPF, проблем возникать не должно, т.к. не должно возникать самого _желания_ работать на уровне presentation, а не viewmodel.

Comment: WinForms конечно, ТЗ стояло максимум простоты и минимум функционала "от дурака".

Comment: В любом случае, идите не от текстбоксов и форм, а от объектов, которые этими текстбоксами представлены. Семантика кода уровня представления должна быть тупая: всегда показывать состояние модельного объекта. Вам в принципе не должно хотеться «обнулить текстбоксы».

Answer (score 1):

Вам может помочь что-то подобное:

```
var tbxs = form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
foreach(TextBox tbx in tbxs)
{
   tbx.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Хотя это, конечно, костыль.

Comment: В целом да, похоже на правду... Но как это можно вклячить в кнопку? Требует ссылку на статический объект, коим бокс не является.

Comment: @VaLenOK007, в смысле вклянчить в кнопку? в хэндлер клика?

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно именно **всех** (с любой степенью вложенности), то в этом Вам поможет рекурсия. Делаем функцию которая будет искать TextBox'ы:

```
void ResetTextBoxes(ControlCollection controls)
{
   foreach(Control c in controls)
   {
      TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
      if (tb != null)
      {
         tb.Text = string.Empty; 
      }
      ResetTextBoxes(c.Controls);
   }
}
```

Затем там где это нужно (например, в обработчике нажатия кнопки) вызываем ее:

```
ResetTextBoxes(form.Controls);
```

где form - это наша форма. Скорее всего у Вас она будет **this**. В принципе, вместо form может выступать любой контейнер в котором мы хотим "обнулить" текстовые поля, будь то **Panel** или **GroupBox**. Писал по памяти, не проверял. Студии под рукой не было, поэтому мог где-нибудь ошибиться.

**P.S.** А вообще я согласен с [@Flammable](/users/10467/flammable), Вам надо пересмотреть структуру своего "гуя"